# Regex - search for numbers, preceded by a comma or quote, that have no digits before the decimal point

Tags: regex, decimal, sublimetext, negative-lookbehind

So I've been trying to do a regex in Sublime text on a CSV file to find any number that doesn't have any digits before the decimal point. Basically, I need to find any combinations of ".xx or ,.xx in the document and then add a comma after. I tried attacking it from both the positive end (i.e. any .xx with , or ") and also with a negative lookbehind for .xx that does not have a digit in front of it. Nothing seems to work, but since I'm new to regex I'm sure I have the wrong syntax. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Right now I have this

```
(?<!\d)(\.\d{2})
```

which is definitely not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Ctrl-H` to open Search and Replace, select Regex Search (the icon with `.*`):

Search: `([",]\.\d\d)`
Replace: `\1,`

This would not check if there is not already a comma after the number. It just added one.

Tested in Sublime Text 3

Comment: Thanks Net! This seems like it should work, but it actually ends up selecting the cases where there are numbers before the decimal. I tried escaping the . but that didn't work either. Confused.

Comment: Is it just two digits after or more?

Comment: The regex don't match the following line `0.55` nor `,0.55` nor `"0.55`, because it search an `"` or `,` followed exclusively by `.`. updated regex, the old regex don't match already the previous text, using now literal `.` and not any charater.

Comment: Net - i know, it totally makes sense what you're saying

Comment: just realized that I also had whole word and wrap selected in the search box. Unclicked those and everything works. Sorry for the false alarm guys!!

Answer (score 1):

Use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd> to open the **Search and Replace**, enable *Regular Expression* <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>

```
Find What: [,"]\.\d{2}\K
Replace With: ,
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is something that worked:

```
sed 's/[,"]\.[0-9][0-9]*/&,/'
```

Comment: thanks unxnut! I've tried that too, but no joy yet. I'm wondering whether it's something specific to Sublime.